# Spark streaming Job aborted due to stage failure when reading from kafka topic

Tags: scala, apache-spark, streaming, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I'm new in spark and kafka and I'm using spark streaming to process data coming from a kafka topic. For now, I just want to print the records in the console. 
I have a mini cluster with spark on two nodes (scala version 2.12.2 and spark-2.1.1) and a node with kafka (version kafka_2.11-0.10.2.0). 
However when I submit my code I get this error :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 3, 1.3.64.64, executor 1): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/GenTraversableOnce$class
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaRDD$KafkaRDDIterator.<init>(KafkaRDD.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaRDD.compute(KafkaRDD.scala:185)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:322)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Does it have something to do with the versions ? Or maybe my code is not correct !

Here is my code :

```
import java.util.UUID
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord
import runtime.ScalaRunTime.stringOf
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.ConsumerStrategies.Subscribe


object followProduction {

def main(args: Array[String]) = {

val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setMaster("spark://<real adress here : 10. ...>:7077").setAppName("followProcess")
val streamContext = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(2))

streamContext.checkpoint("checkpoint")

val kafkaParams = Map[String, Object](
  "bootstrap.servers" -> "1.3.64.66:9094",
  "key.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
  "value.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
  "group.id" -> s"${UUID.randomUUID().toString}",
  "auto.offset.reset" -> "earliest",
  "enable.auto.commit" -> (false: java.lang.Boolean)
)

val topics = Array("test")
val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
  streamContext,
  PreferConsistent,
  Subscribe[String, String](topics, kafkaParams)
)

stream.print()

//stream.map(record => (record.key, record.value)).count().print()

streamContext.start()
streamContext.awaitTermination()
}
}
```

And here is my built :

```
name := "test"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.12.2"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.10" % "2.1.1" %"provided"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming_2.10" % "2.1.1" %"provided"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.10" % "2.0.0"

assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
  case x => MergeStrategy.first
}
```

Any help will be appreciated and thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spark 2.1.x is compiled against Scala 2.11, not 2.12.

Try:

```
scalaVersion := 2.11.11
```

Any 2.11.x version should work.

Also, your Kafka streaming dependency is referring to Scala 2.10, when you need 2.11:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11" % "2.1.1"
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I still get the same error after changing scala version

Comment: @Asmaas Did you install Scala 2.11 in your cluster nodes?

Comment: yes I did. And I get this when I run 'scala -version' : Scala code runner version 2.11.11 -- Copyright 2002-2017, LAMP/EPFL

Comment: @Asmaam See my update, you had another version mismatch.

Comment: It was indeed scala version the problem. I used Scala 2.10.6 and it worked ! Thank's a lot for the insight

Answer (score 0):

Apart from your version mismatches, I think you are running Spark Cluster for which you need to submit all your `JARS` (libs) to the Spark slave machines(nodes) from your actual application where you are running with Spark driver.

You can submit `jars` with `SparkConf` using method `.setJars(libs)`.

Something like this

```
lazy val conf: SparkConf = new SparkConf()
    .setMaster(sparkMaster)
    .setAppName(sparkAppName)
    .set("spark.app.id", sparkAppId)
    .set("spark.submit.deployMode", "cluster")
    .setJars(libs) //setting jars for sparkContext
```

**Note:** `libs: Seq[String]` i.e sequence of library paths

Comment: Thank you for your response, I will look into this